# Having difficulty passing a string back to previous View Controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

I am trying to pass a string value back to the previous view controller using a delegate.  Everything appears to work correct, except for some reason the string value that I send back is not being displayed in the UITextField in the first View Controller where I want it to.

Here is my relevant code:

ViewController "B" (the one passing the data back to the previous View Controller):

```
    protocol CountryFieldProtocol {
        func setField(countryName: String)
    }

    class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

        var countryProtocol: CountryFieldProtocol?
    ...

    func dismiss() {

        for item in countries {
            if item.isSelected == true {
                print("what is the country selected?" + item.name)
                countryProtocol?.setField(item.name)
            }
        }

        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
```

Here is the code in ViewController "A" (the one receiving the data from View Controller "B"):

```
func setField(countryName: String) {

        textField.text = countryName
        print("the country selected is:" + textField.text!)
    }


    @IBAction func textFieldEditing(sender: AnyObject) {

        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        let tableViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CountryList") as? TableViewController
        tableViewController?.countryProtocol = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tableViewController!, animated: true)

    }
```

In my code above, the second View Controller is called when the user selects the textField.  The user is then taken to a UITableView where the user is able to select an item from the list.  After the selection is made, the user clicks on the "Done" button from the navigation bar, and should be taken back to the first View Controller.

In theory, what is supposed to happen is that the users selection from the list should appear in the textfield in the first View Controller.  Unfortunately, while the selection is printed out to the console from the setField function in the first View Controller, the string does not appear in the textField.  Can anyone see what it is I am doing wrong?

Comment: your approach is not good, if you are building a form i suggest using Eureka: https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka

Comment: Can you show where you set `countryProtocol` on view controller b

Comment: Are you clearing the textfield's value in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear? Both functions get called after setField does. If I create the project with just the code that you have posted, it all works.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm setting it in the dismiss function where I have the line: countryProtocol?.setField(item.name)

Comment: @KevinLow I haven't implemented either viewDidAppear nor viewWillAppear

Comment: No, where do you set `countryProtocol=self` to actually set VCA as the delegate?

Comment: It should be where you push view controller b

Comment: @Paulw11  I do it inside the textFieldEditing() method.

Answer (score 0):

Countryprotocol is declared as optional and never instantiated, so setField() is never called because countryProtocol is nil.

You should "fill" that var, and the best place to do it is the first viewcontroller segue.

Comment: setField() does get called, as the value of the string is printed via the print statement.

Comment: The print is called when item.isSelected == true, while setField is called when countryProtocol is not nil

Comment: I am getting output from both print statements.  I have the output to prove it since the print messages are distinct.

Comment: Does it works if you do: countryProtocols?.textField.text = item.name

Comment: That doesn't work because countryProtocols is declared in the second View Controller, not the first.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank everyone who either commented or submitted a solution.  I figured out the problem, and one person actually was on the right track when he said that he replicated my work and got it working as intended.

I was able to solve this problem by deleting the textField that I had created from the storyboard, added another one instead of it, and then rewired it to the appropriate outlets.  Everything worked smoothly after that.  I have no logical explanation as to why this worked, but it did all the same.

Thanks once again to everyone who attempted to find a solution for me.

All the best.